# What kind of compact fluorescent light bulb fixture is this?

Tags: light-fixture, recessed-lighting, fluorescent

I have search quite a bit to find what kind of compact fluorescent light bulb I need for this recessed can light?  It is in a bathroom above a tub.  I have include a picture of the base looking into it.  It has four electric blades, two on each side.  I tried buying a G24Q-I 4-pin base CFL bulb but that was too big.

I have looked at all the bases [here](https://www.bulbs.com/bulbfinder.aspx?state=4&N=14%201273) but don't see any that match.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a picture of the ballast too.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a gx23-2 base for a 13w cfl [like this](https://amzn.to/35p9Emj):
[image]

Comment: Thank you, so I think I was assuming the four metal tabs were the electrical contacts.  If this is the bulb then that means the electrics contacts are the two small holes on the base, does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, the pins are the contacts. Literally installed thousands of those in the 1990's.

Comment: This was it!  Thanks a lot.  I couldnt have found the right one without you.

Answer (score 0):

It is a compact lamp but without the wattage there could be dozens of possible matches. If you open the fixture and can identify the ballast we can figure it out. I think there are 6 different bases and each one has different configurations based on number of tubes, length of tubes and wattages, so much more information is needed.
Something like a cftr42  or gx24q/841 are possibilities but not sure.

Comment: Thanks alot.  The only other info I can on the ballast is in the newly added picture.  I can't find any markings on the base at all.